# Convert to 12 hr format

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a the following fields on the UI: datepicker, hours dropdown, minutes dropdown, and am/pm dropdown.

In my controller I am trying to tie these fields together and create a DateTime value like this (5/18/2012 2:45 PM):

```
model.Scheduled = new DateTime(model.Scheduled.Value.Year, model.Scheduled.Value.Month, model.Scheduled.Value.Day, model.ScheduledHour + (model.ScheduledAMPM == "AM" ? 0 : 12), model.ScheduledMinute, 0);
```

This works in most of the cases, but not when I select 12 on the hour dropdown. How should I refactor the above line of code so that it works in all cases?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  DateTime does not hold a specific format.  What is your exact question?  more code is required to help you.

Comment: Which language is this for? Pick either C# or Vb, not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert 12 AM and 12 PM to 0 and 12 by taking the Hour modulo 12:

```
(model.ScheduledHour % 12) + (model.ScheduledAMPM == "AM" ? 0 : 12)
```

I would also recommend writing unit tests to verify all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the method `DateTime. TryParse(string input, out DateTime output)` method to have C# do the translation for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-cus/library/ch92fbc1.aspx